# bash wait for open app to complete before continuing

Tags: bash, macos

I have a problem with timing in a BASH script.

```
#!/usr/local/bash
open /apps/my.app #this generates a text file; may take a few seconds. Then the app closes.
sed 's/....' new_text_file.txt; #this modifies the text file
```

How best do I wait for the app to finish properly before the `sed` takes place?  Currently the `open` command sets up a background task like a NOHUP, and the script proceeds immediately to the `sed`. 
If it helps, the app is an OSX Automator workflow converted to an app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-W` flag of `open` to wait for the app to quit:

```
#!/usr/local/bash
open -W /apps/my.app #this generates a text file; may take a few seconds. Then the app closes.
sed 's/....' new_text_file.txt; #this modifies the text file
```